# Getting the size of a folder

Tags: c++, file, size

I am working in visual studio 2015, on windows. Is there any possibility to get the size of each file or folder from a path in this code:
I need to obtain size like a int, number of kilobytes

```
vector<string>listDirectories(const char *path) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);

    vector<string> directories;

    struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir);

    while (entry != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
            directories.push_back(entry->d_name);

        entry = readdir(dir);
    }

    closedir(dir);
    return directories;


}
```

Comment: Brute force would [be to call `stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on the names of all files in the directory (and its sub directories. Yay recursion!) and sum up the `stat::st_size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new `<filesystem>` header you indeed can, just `#include <experimental/filesystem>`(experimental as it is a C++17 feature - but this is fine as you state you are using VS2015 so it's available to use) and check out the following to do what you need:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/file_size

`std::experimental::filesystem::file_size` returns the size of the file given by the path in an integral number of bytes, note that this `path` is not a `const char*` or `std::string` path but rather a `fs::path` as part of the filesystem header.

Assuming the function in the question returns a list of files in a directory, you could do (untested) to print each file size in the given directory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <vector>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

//...

int main(void) {
    std::vector<std::string> file_names_vec = listDirectories("dir");

    size_t folder_size = 0;
    for (auto it = file_names_vec.begin(); it != file_names_vec.end(); ++it) {
         fs::path p = *it;
         std::cout << "Size of file: " << *it << " = " << fs::file_size(p) << " bytes";
         folder_size += fs::file_size(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and how can obtain the size of folders?

Comment: @Sebi95 You could simply sum the sizes of each file inside the folder to obtain the folder size

Comment: Hmm, and if a have subfolders in that folder

Comment: @Sebi95 You would need to apply the same method recursively to the sub-folder taking care to avoid applying `fs::file_size` to any folder (just requires if-statement for checking).

Comment: Ok, one more question, how can i print the size in C, i don't know the format