# How cand i get the size of every subdirectory and every file from a specified path in c++ using windows?

Tags: c++, file, path, directory, size

I want to get the size in KB of every sub directory and every file from a specified path in c++ using Windows. How can I do that? 
Thank you!

Comment: Read this answer and its comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925472/getting-the-size-of-a-folder

Answer (score 2):

With the new `<filesystem>` header you could do this, just `#include <experimental/filesystem>`(experimental as it is a C++17 feature) and check out the following to do what you need:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/file_size

`std::experimental::filesystem::file_size` returns the size of the file given by the path in an integral number of bytes, note that this `path` is not a `const char*` or `std::string` path but rather a `fs::path` as part of the filesystem header.

You can apply this recursively to each folder from a given `path` to get the sizes of all files and folders (sum the file sizes in a folder to get folder size).

**Note: this requires access to an environment which has experimental c++17 features available.**

Comment: I`m working in Visual Studio 2010, so... and I don`t know how to use fs::path. I read the path as a string and I get the list of subdirectories and files from that path in a vector<string>. A little more help please! 10x!

Comment: @DinaBogdan Windows API `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx